# Getting values of a JSON?

Tags: android, json, web-services

I'm trying get a value of a JSON that my web service return. I never use JSON I always use SOAP, but today I need use JSON and I dont know how can I get values this.

My web service returns this JSON: `{"cod":999,"msg":"User Data.","return":{"ID":"74","name":"FERNANDO PAIVA","email":"fernando@mydomain.com"}}`.

I want get email for example, how can I do this ?

I'm trying this.

```
//make a get in web service, return a String with JSON format
public String get(String url){
        String s = "";

        try {
            //executa o get
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);         
            httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + getBasicAuthentication());            
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
            //trata o retorno do get
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
            String line = "";
            String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while((line = bReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(line + lineSeparator);             
            }
            bReader.close();            
            //
            s = stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return s;
    }


//return a value of JSON 
public String getUsuarioByEmail(){
        String url = "mydomain.com.br/json.php?email=fernando@mydomain.com.br";
        String response = httpClient.get(url);
        JSONArray jArray = null;
        String ss = "";
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            jArray = obj.getJSONArray("return");
            for(int x = 0; x < jArray.length(); x++){
                JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(x);
                ss = e.getString("email");              
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return ss;
    }
```

Comment: jArray = obj.getJSONArray("return"); its also jsonobject

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: @DavidePastore not a duplicate...2 post are distinct

Comment: yes it is ... it seems like you do not understand JSON basics ("return" is not an array) ... and asking such(too localized) question will not help anyone in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);
if (responseObj.optInt("cod") == 99) // Response code validation, add your logic here
{
    JSONObject returnObj = responseObj.optJSONObject("return");
    if (returnObj != null)
    {
         String email = returnObj.optString("email");
    }
}
```

Using `opt***` methods does not throw `JSONException`, unlike `get***` method, which throw `JSONException` if the mapping does not exist. Use the appropriate method, depending on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you want  :

```
try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject returnObject = obj.getJSONObject("return");
           String email = returnObject.getString("email");
           //so on


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's all:

```
//return a value of JSON 
public String getUsuarioByEmail(){
    String url = "mydomain.com.br/json.php?email=fernando@mydomain.com.br";
    String response = httpClient.get(url);
    JSONArray jArray = null;
    String ss = "";
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
        obj = obj.getJSONObject("return");
        ss = obj.getString("email");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return ss;
}
```

Comment: I've not read your comment. It would have been impossible for me. :)